# Difficulty in working out trivial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let me preface that I haven't done differential equations in many years therefore I'm trying to be very thorough in understanding solutions. I have the equation

$$\frac{d^2g(y)}{dy^2}+\lambda g(y)=0$$

with boundary conditions $\frac{dg(y)}{dy}=0$ at $y=0,b$ where $b$ is a constant. I was able to work out why the solution $\lambda<0$ gives a trivial solution but I'm stumped at finding the trivial solution for $\lambda=0$.

In this case the original equation should become

$$\frac{d^2g(y)}{dy^2}=0$$

so if I integrate I get

$$\frac{dg(y)}{dy}=c_1$$

Using the boundary conditions I know that $\frac{dg(0)}{dy}=\frac{dg(b)}{dy}=0=c_1$. Now I'm now sure if I should stop here or not. This is not the trivial solution, is it? Integrating again gives

$$g(y)=c_1y+c_2=c_2$$

which I have no boundary conditions for to work out $c_2$. I know for a fact this equation should have the trivial solution $c_1=c_2=0$ for $\lambda=0$ but I think I'm doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No, you are complicate it too much. You don't have boundary conditions for $c_2$, so any $c_2$ is a solution. Just plug it back into the original equation, and you see that it verifies it, including all your conditions. So if you must have $c_2=0$, that means you forgot to write an additional constraint on the boundary conditions.

Comment: Thanks but I re-checked and I'm pretty sure there are no other boundary conditions. Before the separation of variables the boundary conditions were $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial y}=-x$ and $\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x}=y$.

Comment: What was your original equation?

Comment: The original problem is that I need to solve the following partial differential for $\psi(x,y)$ where $G_x$ and $G_y$ are constants,

$$
G_x(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial x^2})+G_y(\frac{\partial^2\psi}{\partial y^2})=0
$$

The boundary conditions for it are

$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial x}=2y
$$

at $x=0,a$ and

$$
\frac{\partial\psi}{\partial y}=0
$$

at $y=0,b$. I set $\psi=\phi +xy$ then used separation of variables.

Comment: If the gradient is $0$ at 2 points than a constant solution is a non-trivial solution.